# Auth::attempt always returns false

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Auth:attempt always returns false

I have checked that the column name 'password' is spelled correctly and that i hashed the password before adding the user to the DB since attempt will hash the password and check the hashed password against the hashed string in the DB.
Also made sure that eloquent indeed works on the desired user table.
Tried adding implements Authenticatable to the user model  but didn't work.

RegisterController

```
protected function create(array $data)
{
    return User::create([
        'name' => $data['name'],
        'email' => $data['email'],
        'password' => bcrypt($data['password']),
    ]);
}
```

User Model - current user model

```
class User extends Authenticatable{
  protected $table = 'users';
  public $timestamps = false;

  protected $attributes = [ 'rate' => 0];
  protected $fillable = ['name', 'email', 'password'];
  protected $visible = ['name', 'email', 'rate'];

}
```

Login Controller - auto generated and ofc uses the AuthenticatesUsers class and both of them are untouched by me

```
 class LoginController extends Controller
 {


     use AuthenticatesUsers;

     /**
      * Where to redirect users after login.
      *
      * @var string
      */
     protected $redirectTo = '/home';

     /**
      * Create a new controller instance.
      *
      * @return void
      */
     public function __construct()
     {
         $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
     }
 }
```

Table stracture is

```
    Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->string('name');
        $table->string('email',100)->unique();
        $table->double('rate');
        $table->string('password');
    });
```

config/auth.php is

return [

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Defaults
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| This option controls the default authentication "guard" and password
| reset options for your application. You may change these defaults
| as required, but they're a perfect start for most applications.
|
*/

'defaults' => [
    'guard' => 'web',
    'passwords' => 'users',
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Authentication Guards
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Next, you may define every authentication guard for your application.
| Of course, a great default configuration has been defined for you
| here which uses session storage and the Eloquent user provider.
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| Supported: "session", "token"
|
*/

'guards' => [
    'web' => [
        'driver' => 'session',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],

    'api' => [
        'driver' => 'token',
        'provider' => 'users',
    ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Resetting Passwords
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| You may specify multiple password reset configurations if you have more
| than one user table or model in the application and you want to have
| separate password reset settings based on the specific user types.
|
| The expire time is the number of minutes that the reset token should be
| considered valid. This security feature keeps tokens short-lived so
| they have less time to be guessed. You may change this as needed.
|
*/

'passwords' => [
    'users' => [
        'provider' => 'users',
        'table' => 'password_resets',
        'expire' => 60,
    ],
],
```

];

I used the auth:make command so most of the code was auto generated

When debbuging with xdebug and throwing dd commands all i got from attemptLogin is false, attempt returns false as well.

edit- table was changed to users and on create method tried using Hash::make instead and still get false response

**edit 2 -** For some strange reason Hash:Check now returns true but attempt still returns false.

**edit 3 -** Attempt is used just for debugging, the function handaling the login is:

```
    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);
        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can 
automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the 
username and
    // the IP address of the client making these requests into this 
application.
        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

         // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the 
  number of attempts
          // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of 
  course, when this
          // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get 
 locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);
        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
     }
```

edit 5 - route list:

[image]

Comment: Could you try to run `Hash::check('yourpassword', 'the-database-stored-hash`)` from tinker and tell me if it returns true or false? If that is false, can you post as well the dd output of the $data array in the create method of the RegistrationController?

Comment: Hash::check returns false, the dd shows:
 array:5 [▼
  "_token" => "ZY8EKm9GAIYsqz8m3hmGksRrVZPsJnuEaGigibXS"
  "name" => "asd"
  "email" => "user@user.com"
  "password" => "123123"
  "password_confirmation" => "123123"
]
this is the $data that arrives to the create function before going throught User::Create

Comment: That's strange that the hash check returns false. Could you try to replace `bcrypt($data['password'])` with `Hash::make($data['password'])` in the user creation and post the relevant config/auth.php?

Comment: Does your User model have a `setPasswordAttribute()` method that isn't shown above?  If so, you may be hashing your password twice during creation.  This could explain why you are getting `Hash::check()`:`false`.

Comment: setPasswordAttribute() method isn't here
also now for some strage reason Hash::check returns true but attempt return false.
i tried chainging bcrypt to Hash::make and still no change in attempt state

Comment: Please post the method where you are using `Auth:attempt()`.

Comment: I used Auth:attempt when trying to debug the app, in fact the method handling the login is in the AuthanticatesUsers class written by laravel, I will edit the post now with it

Comment: @matticustard it should be this one [(source)](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.1/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Auth/AuthenticatesUsers.php) but it's the core laravel trait. He seems to be using that one

Comment: Can you as well post the output of `php artisan route:list` output? Might be a middleware issue

Comment: Just a note, if your table is named `user` it should say `protected $table = 'user';` in your User model, not `protected $table = 'users';` as it does above.

Comment: Yes this is the edited User model i have changed it a min ago, since i changed the table name to 'users' i have also changed the model to 'users'.
editing post now to add the route:list

Comment: And remove the implements Authenticatable and the methods that have been added with it, as by default laravel would make the User model extend the Authenticatable model, which should already define these methods.

Comment: As @mdexp says, It should just be `class User extends Authenticatable`.  You don't need to define those authentication methods unless you want to override them for some reason.

Comment: removed the implements and changed it to extends Authenticatable